# Prisma ORM optional relations for user models

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, backend, prisma

I am using Prisma ORM with PostgreSQL backend for my database, I have users as students and admins and they have slightly different fields so I created a base model `User` for common info as well as two more models `Admin` and `Student` for further unique info but I can't create an admin (a user referencing an admin) without also referencing it to a student, can anybody help with schema structure?

```
// schema.prisma

enum Role {
  SUPERADMIN
  ADMIN
  STUDENT
}

model User {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  citizenId String   @unique
  hash      String
  role      Role     @default(STUDENT)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  student Student? @relation(fields: [citizenId], references: [citizenId], map: "user_student_fk")
  admin   Admin?   @relation(fields: [citizenId], references: [citizenId], map: "user_admin_fk")
}

model Admin {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  citizenId String   @unique
  name      String
  schoolId  Int
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  user   User?
  school School @relation(fields: [schoolId], references: [id])
}

model Student {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  citizenId String   @unique
  name      String
  classId   Int
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  user    User?
  class   Class        @relation(fields: [classId], references: [id])
  results TestResult[]
}

// ...
```